# Extract value from Mysql to HDFS using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I have requirements where `sqoop` should extract data from `mysql` table with groupby in the query.
Is is possible in the `sqoop`?

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/sqoop-import-data-from-mysql-to-hive

Answer (score 0):

Please use the --query  or -e  parameter on sqoop data import for custom queries over the data. This will help to fulfill.